# Pass injected dependency to child component in Angular

Tags: angular

I want to pass a function to a child component but the function contains calling a service, I mean API call. When the component rendered I see the error that "Cannot read property 'lockUser' of undefined". lockUser is a function of the service.

In child component:

```
<ngx-child
  [settings]="settings"
  [source]="localSource"
  (delete)="delete($event)"
>
</ngx-child>
```

in parent component:

```
<ngx-parent
    [settings]="settings"
    [delete]="deleteUser"
    [source]="test"
></ngx-parent>


 public deleteUser($event: any) {
    this.service.lockUser($event.data).subscribe(
      (_) =>
        this.loadUsers().then(() =>
          this.toast.success(
            this.translate.translate('User Removed'),
            this.translate.translate('Success'),
          ),
        ),
      (err) =>
        this.toast.danger(
          this.translate.translate('Something went wrong'),
          this.translate.translate('Error'),
        ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Why do you need to pass function call to child component?

Comment: Because I wanna make it reusable and in different situations it gets different functions.
Basically it is a table and I wanna show different entities in, like users, products, etc.
then for delete user I have to call user service and for product I have to use product sertvice.

Comment: The point of DI is that you have loose coupling between your components. By passing a function from parent to child components, you're making your components tightly coupled again wich 1) scatters your logic 2) makes your components hard to unittest

Comment: I suggest adding another service containing the deleteUser method, injecting this service in both components so you can call the method from both places.

Comment: Sure. Testability is a more important thing. Actually the child component has a delete input property that regarding the usage of parent component sometimes it should call deleteUser and sometime deleteProduct. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

I guess, something triggers the execution of this function in the child. You have two options:

### 1. Child's event triggers the execution in the parent

Create an `@Output` in your child component and listen to this event in the parent. Execute the delete function in your parent when the event is fired.

child.component.ts:

```js
@Output() public someEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();
...
public onSomeEvent($event) {
  someEvent.emit($event);
}
```

parent.component.html:

```html
<ngx-parent
    [settings]="settings"
    (someEvent)="deleteUser($event)"
    [source]="test"
></ngx-parent>
```

### 2. Execute the function directly in the child

You could also inject the dependencies right here in the child and execute the delete function here, without passing it as a parameter. If you have a good reason to execute it in the parent, stay with the 1. solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Used option 1 to implement a reusable button component.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I just have to bind the execution context to the child component because as you can see I have got an error that said "Cannot read property 'lockUser' of **undefined**". So just I passed the **this**(execution context) to  child component with ES5 arrow function:

```
public deleteUser = ($event: any) => {
    this.service.lockUser($event.data).subscribe(
      (_) =>
        this.loadUsers().then(() =>
          this.toast.success(
            this.translate.translate('User Removed'),
            this.translate.translate('Success'),
          ),
        ),
      (err) =>
        this.toast.danger(
          this.translate.translate('Something went wrong'),
          this.translate.translate('Error'),
        ),
    );
  }
```